# JQ argument error in bash script

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a problem with a JQ query:

```
max=$(script) <-- (return integer)
jq  -r ".notifiestext | map(select(.read==false))" temp_notif |
  jq --arg foo "$max" "map(select(.id<$foo))"
```

I get the following error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ')' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1: map(select(.id<))
```

The ".id" parameter is an integer

Any solution?

Comment: Better [edit] the question directly instead of adding comments. Also, use indentation for code blocks instead of multi-line backticks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the `$` for `$foo` so that the shell doesn't try to expand it as a parameter before `jq` even runs.

```
jq -r ".notifiestext | map(select(.read==false))" temp_notif |
  jq --arg foo "$max" "map(select(.id<\$foo))"
```

It would be better to use single quotes for the `jq` filter instead.

```
jq -r '.notifiestext | map(select(.read==false))' temp_notif |
  jq --arg foo "$max" 'map(select(.id<$foo))'
```

Comment: It should also be noted that the second call to jq is completely unnecessary. It could have been written with a single call.

Comment: To be honest, I never even looked at what either call was actually doing.